# How do I build a scratch-resistant computer desk for filming?

Tags: desk

I currently have a desk that takes quite a bit of room and scratches very easily since its painted wood. As it is, my room isn't that big to begin with. I want to build a floating desk (Wall mounted) where I can build my electrical projects and looks beautiful on video since ill be recording my projects to make tutorials. I've never build a desk so I am not very sure where to start. I will probably be building it in a corner so the desk curves. I want to avoid a wooden tabletop because many of the things i will be working with tend to scratch the surface. I have my desktop screen mounted on the wall to save room already. Ill probably put the tower in the middle under the desk. What materials should I buy to mount the desk? Also what can I use to help prevent the top of the desk from being scratched?

Comment: You can build the desk with lumber and just search for ways to put plastic or other material on top of the desk so you don't sit your materials on the actual wood. Woodworking is fun. Just search google for ideas, and draw up a design plan yourself. You will be very satisfied when it's done, knowing that you designed and made it on your own. *I personally wouldn't go for a wall mounted table/desk... unless you mean you also will support the desk with desk legs but also connected to the wall.*

Comment: Precut countertop laminate is cheap at the big box stores. Sometimes they'll also have granite countertop 'scraps' that'd make fine desktops. **Solid** oak with a polyurethane finish is quite scratch resistant, and nice for electronics projects. Look for an old library table; although they seem to have gotten pricey since the 90's.

Answer (score 1):

Look up DIY concrete countertops. Pretty easy and strong. You can find someone to weld a desk for you that will look modern for next to nothing out of square tubing.

Comment: Thank you. Will do! I know a few welders. This should be nice.